# How do I start ArangoDB cluster in active failover mode?

Tags: arangodb

I try to follow this, but I can't seem to make it work: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/active-failover/manual-start/

ArangoDB version 3.3.7.

I try to start 3 nodes (3 agents). I believe officially I can start only 2 dbservers, but I heard 3 dbservers should also work.

Comment: Can you add your steps which you did?

Comment: I'm looking for a working example. Something that could be in the ArangoDB docs for example. I.e. I'm not looking for "pseudo-code" type of example, but a real working example.

Comment: (Of course the ip addresses don't have to work as such, but I'm looking for something that has worked somewhere at some point in time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it wasn't easy, but here are the commands. Note that you probably don't want to expose the database to the world without authentication (and maybe traffic encryption).

Server 1 (172.31.54.123):

```
arangod --server.endpoint tcp://172.31.54.123:8531 --server.storage-engine rocksdb --database.directory /data/agent --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.jwt-secret verysecret --log.file /data/agent.log --log.force-direct false --foxx.queues false --server.statistics false --agency.activate true --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --agency.my-address tcp://172.31.54.123:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531

arangod --server.endpoint tcp://172.31.54.123:8529 --server.storage-engine rocksdb --database.directory /data/arangodb --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.jwt-secret verysecret --log.file /data/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --replication.automatic-failover true --cluster.my-address tcp://172.31.54.123:8529 --cluster.my-role SINGLE --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.54.123:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531
```

Server 2 (172.31.63.137):

```
arangod --server.endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --server.storage-engine rocksdb --database.directory /data/agent --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.jwt-secret verysecret --log.file /data/agent.log --log.force-direct false --foxx.queues false --server.statistics false --agency.activate true --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --agency.my-address tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531

arangod --server.endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8529 --server.storage-engine rocksdb --database.directory /data/arangodb --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.jwt-secret verysecret --log.file /data/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --replication.automatic-failover true --cluster.my-address tcp://172.31.63.137:8529 --cluster.my-role SINGLE --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.54.123:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531
```

Server 3 (172.31.48.49):

```
arangod --server.endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531 --server.storage-engine rocksdb --database.directory /data/agent --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.jwt-secret verysecret --log.file /data/agent.log --log.force-direct false --foxx.queues false --server.statistics false --agency.activate true --agency.size 3 --agency.supervision true --agency.my-address tcp://172.31.48.49:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --agency.endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531

arangod --server.endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8529 --server.storage-engine rocksdb --database.directory /data/arangodb --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.jwt-secret verysecret --log.file /data/arangod.log --log.force-direct false --foxx.queues false --server.statistics true --replication.automatic-failover true --cluster.my-address tcp://172.31.48.49:8529 --cluster.my-role SINGLE --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.54.123:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.63.137:8531 --cluster.agency-endpoint tcp://172.31.48.49:8531
```

IP addresses will of course be different, but overall this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the ArangoDB starter to start an ActiveFailover deployment here
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/active-failover/using-the-arangodb-starter/

Or the cluster, where you may employ arbitrary numbers of db servers and coordinators here:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/cluster/

Comment: Sorry, but at this point I'm looking for a manual startup without the starter.

Comment: And also I can't use the cluster for a few reasons, I need to use the active failover for now.

Comment: Sure. I was trying to get you started. Good luck.

Comment: I have used the starter but it's an extra piece of software which I would like to avoid. There may be some issues with it too (currently there are some).

Comment: I understand. So when u use the starter look at there Arangod processes, which it started and copy those command lines for your own purposes. That's all the starter does.